# ¿Por qué int? != int?

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de obtener un int desde un modelo declarado de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Modelo
{
    public int? IntNullable { get; set; }
}
```

pero al ser nullable no me permite convertirlo a int normal.

¿Por qué?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No te lo permite por una razón muy sencilla: si el valor de tu entero `nullable` es `null`, el entero "normal" no podría almacenar el valor.

Hay muchas soluciones posibles, una muy sencilla y clara sería la siguiente:

```
int entero = IntNullable ?? 0;
```

Se comprueba si el valor de `IntNullable` es `null`. Si es asi, se asigna un 0 al entero. En caso contrario, se almacena el valor de la variable.

Otra opción es usar `GetValueOrDefault`, presente desde .Net 4.0 para los tipos `Nullables`:

```
int entero = IntNullable.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

Añadir el interrogante `?` es sólo un [azúcar sintáctico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Az%C3%BAcar_sint%C3%A1ctico) para [`System.Nullable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/). No puedes asignar un objeto a una primitiva:

```
int i = new System.Nullable<int>();
```

> ```
> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'.
> ```

Pero puedes convertirlo al tipo subyacente:

```
int i = (int)(new System.Nullable<int>());
//      ^^^^^ <---- Convierte a int
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Aunque el código anterior provoca una excepción:

> ```
> System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
> ```

Esto sucede porque los *nullables* pueden ser nulos, pero las primitivas no. Si le asignas un valor al *nullable* evitas la excepción:

```
int i = (int)(new System.Nullable<int>(42));
Console.WriteLine(i); // Muestra 42
```

Comment: con primitiva, ¿a que te refieres?, nunca escuché esa expresión.

Comment: Me refiero a un tipo [*built-in*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/built-in-types-table) que sea simple (consulta el apartado *Remarks*).